# Pinterest API Rate Limits

Tags: pinterest

We currently use our applications to download some pins information for analytics purposes
Currently we hit the API on hourly basis but we have some problems with rate limiting, so we need the following questions to be addresses:

1. The documentation states that the rate limit is 1000 calls per hour per user token per endpoint. By looking at the HTTP headers apparently the actual limit is 200. So, which is the correct one?
2. Are GET **/v1/pins/1234** and GET **/v1/pins/5678** considered to be a call to the same endpoint?
3. Are there any application level (so, despite of the used user token) rate-limit in place?
4. Are there any IP level rate limits?
5. Since we use concurrent requests, are there any limitation on the number of CONCURRENT request? (which means: make another call from the same IP and using the same token, even if the previous one hasn't ended yet)

Thanks in advance.

PS: I tried to contact them via support form, but it returns a 422. Which is awesome!

Comment: Did you ever find answers to these questions?

Comment: Unfortunately no, nothing at all.

Answer (score 1):

For apps that is still in development stage the limit is 200. You will get 1000 if your apps passed the review.

Comment: now in development stage the 10 requests per hour .after review 1000 calls per hour.

Comment: And effective April 29, 2020 the rate limit for "pending" applications is 1 per hour, and after review the limit is 100 per day per App. https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/api/overview/

Answer (score 0):

> - *The documentation states that the rate limit is 1000 calls per hour
>     per user token per endpoint. By looking at the HTTP headers
>     apparently the actual limit is 200. So, which is the correct one?*

Ans: Its 10 per token per app id per hour for app in development(tested), 1000 per token per hour for production app.

> - *Are there any application level (so, despite of the used user token)
>     rate-limit in place?*

Ans: No, rate limit will be 10(app in development) or 1000(approved app)/hour for each tokens you have

> - *Are there any IP level rate limits?*

Ans: No

> - *Since we use concurrent requests, are there any limitation on the number of CONCURRENT request? (which means: make another call from the same IP and using the same token, even if the previous one hasn't ended yet)*

Ans: No there is no such limit but they will probably check for **bot activity** and you may end up with **banned account**, so please do maintain some **delay in between requests for same token** IMO 12 seconds should be enough